# Как импортировать на сайт wordpress пользователей на кириллице?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

На сайте под управлением wordpress установлен [плагин Имена пользователей на кириллице](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/allow-cyrillic-usernames/). 
С помощью [плагина ClassiPress Ads Importer plugin](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/appthemes-classipress-ads-importer-plugin/) импортирую пользователей с объявлениями.

Если имена пользователей на латинице, то все отрабатывает отлично, но если авторы прописаны кириллицей, то независимо новые пользователи это или существующие - в строке

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(intval($term['term_taxonomy_id'])), 'ad_cat');
```

получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array

, причем сам пользователь успевает зарегистрироваться (отображается в админке)

Понимаю, что импорт срабатывает раньше, чем плагин **allow-cyrillic-usernames** успевает отработать - как это можно исправить?

файл плагина *classi-importer.class.php*

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $post['post_title'] = $row['post_title'];
  $post['post_content'] = $row['post_content'];
  $post['post_status'] = $row['post_status'];
  $post['post_type'] = 'ad_listing';
  if(isset($row['user_name'])) {    
    $user_id = username_exists($row['user_name']);
          if(!$user_id) {
      $random_password = wp_generate_password(12, false);
      $user_id = wp_create_user($row['user_name'], $random_password);
    }
  } 
  unset($row['user_name']);
  $post['post_author'] = $user_id;
  if(!($term = term_exists($row['ad_cat'], 'ad_cat')))
  $term = wp_insert_term($row['ad_cat'], 'ad_cat');
  $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(intval($term['term_taxonomy_id'])), 'ad_cat');
```

файл **allow-cyrillic-usernames**

```
function acu_sanitize_user($username, $raw_username, $strict) {
    $username = wp_strip_all_tags( $raw_username );
    $username = remove_accents( $username );
    // Kill octets
    $username = preg_replace( '|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $username );
    $username = preg_replace( '/&.+?;/', '', $username ); // Kill entities

    // If strict, reduce to ASCII and Cyrillic characters for max portability.
    if ( $strict )
        $username = preg_replace( '|[^a-zа-я0-9 _.\-@]|iu', '', $username );

    $username = trim( $username );
    // Consolidate contiguous whitespace
    $username = preg_replace( '|\s+|', ' ', $username );

    return $username;
}
add_filter('sanitize_user', 'acu_sanitize_user', 10, 3);
```